# Why is my ListView not binding to the ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding

So I have a VERY simple UI design with a ListView and a button.
I want to populate the listview when clicking the button.

```
 <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

        <ListView Margin="10,10,10,202" Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData.Users}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
```

I have bound the ItemSource property of the ListView to be `SomeData.Users` which is an ObservableCollectiuon which should notify the UI when it's updated, added, removed or refreshed. And then down below where I have the column I am binding the DisplayMember to the `Name` property of the observable collection.

Here is the `SomeData` class

```
public class SomeData
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        public static void Populate()
        {
            Users.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
            Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
            Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" });
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Mail { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the MainWindow.cs

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SomeData.Populate();
        }
```

afaik I shouldnt have to set the DataContext anywhere.. Right?

Comment: Your binding code means: Use the value from DataContext.SomeData.Users

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your Binding syntax is wrong. You are trying to bind to an static property, try this:

```
"{Binding Source={x:Static YourNameSpace:SomeData.Users}}"
```

Or if you are using WPF 4.5 or newer:

```
"{Binding Path=(YourNameSpace:SomeData.Users)}"
```

One tip: with problems like yours always try to take a look to your output window and look for `System.Window.Data Error`, these are commonly binding exceptions that occur when a binding expression can not be resolved. In your case I am sure you will find this exception.

Comment: Ohh.. I've never actually bound to static properties before, that explains alot, and it does not show it in the Output window, not this time atleast but I am sure I will run across it some day

Comment: Also.. I tried binding the namespace it didnt work it told me to do this.. Why local: ? x:Static local:SomeData.Users

Comment: @MarkDenom, sorry if I was not clear enough, I did not mean your type's (class) namespace, but a XAML namespace. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml) for further info =)

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the edition =), forgot to mention that

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the DataContext for the xaml.

Add datacontext to mainwindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = new SomeData();
}
```

and change the xaml ItemsSource binding to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
```

Comment: This is not always true... the OP is binding to an static property, a DataContext is not needed

Comment: Yes that would work, but it is not what the OP is looking for.